# How do I get the number of rows in my paged GridView control?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rows, sqldatasource

The rows.count property on my GridView control only tells me how many rows are displayed on the screen, not the total number available.

The solution below is not working. I have an SqlDataSource and a GridView and neither can be cast into a dataset or datatable.

Comment: **Count** property of your datasource (maybe DataTable).

Comment: Which event or method do I put that code into, after it postbacks?

Comment: Which is the "solution below" that you are referencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SqlDataSource has an event called OnSelected that you can set to a method like the one below -

```
protected void OnSelectedData(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)  
{  
    // Set the record count label  
    RecordCountLabel.Text = "Total Records: " + e.AffectedRows;  
}
```

Notice that the e.AffectedRows contains the total number of rows selected.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to get the rows count of the datasource.

If datasource is datatable then

```
dt.Rows.Count
```

will give the total number of rows where dt is the datatable object.

If it is a dataset then get the corresponding datatable and then take the rows count.

```
ds.Tables["tablename"].Rows.Count;  // give the datatable name
```

or

```
ds.Tables[tableIndex].Rows.Count;  // give the datatable index
```

where ds is the dataset object.