# Records count in asp.net gridview with SQL data source & Paging

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to count to total number of records returned with a SQL query in asp.net gridview, while i am using paging to display only 20 records in a page.
So when i use this code it return only 20 rows(Because of paging.)

```
int totalrow = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.Rows.Count);
```

How can i count the total number or records from Grid view?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" DataSourceMode="DataSet" EnableCaching="true" CacheDuration="1800"
                        runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>"
                        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1.ProviderName %>"
                        SelectCommand="Select * from Table"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the number of rows in my paged GridView control?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437758/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-rows-in-my-paged-gridview-control)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on Page Load

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {       
     int count;            
     System.Data.DataView dv = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
     count  = dv.Count;
 }
```

or you can also do this

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
   int count;
   count = e.AffectedRows;
}
```