# count number of entries in grid view with paging enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `TextBox` in which I want to display the number of entries in my `GridView`.

```
count2.Text += (GV.Rows.Count).ToString();
```

Paging is enabled but it counts only the entries in the first page.

How do I ensure that it counts all entries ?

I tried this :

```
         <asp:SqlDataSource ProviderName="System.Data.SqlClient" ID = "sourceProducts" runat = "server" ConnectionString =" <%$ ConnectionStrings:DB %> " SelectCommand = "myqueryhere"  OnSelected="sourceProducts_Selected">




protected void sourceProducts_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
    {
        z = e.AffectedRows;
    }
```

But this gives me some wrong value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Selected event of [SQLDataSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.selected(v=vs.110).aspx), and fetch the number of records using [**Affected**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcestatuseventargs.affectedrows(v=vs.110).aspx) property like this:-

```
protected void sourceProducts_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    count2.Text = e.AffectedRows.ToString();
}
```

**Edit:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataView dataView = (DataView)sourceProducts
                                              .Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
    count2.Text = dataView .Count.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Hi Rahul, I have already tried that. It gives me some wrong value.

Comment: It gives me a value of 1063.There are only 12 entries in the gridView.10 in the first page and 2 in the second.I think it calculates how many rows are being parsed or something.

Comment: I entered the comment without finishing it :P

Comment: @user1698232 - I think there is something else in your code which is causing this because both these code are working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a step back. Where did you get the data from? If you are binding to a data table then just count the rows there.  If calling to a stored proc with parameters for start and end rows and getting a table back, change it to send a dataset back. The first table in the dataset would be your data, the second a table just containing the count.

Comment: I am using a SqlDataSource. I tried doing what you said.I used OnSelected event on the source.I'll show the code as an edit to the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Just check this, what will be the result in your `selected method`

```
protected void sourceProducts_Selected(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
int startRowOnPage = (GridView1.PageIndex * GridView1.PageSize) + 1;
    int lastRowOnPage = startRowOnPage + GridView1.Rows.Count - 1;
    int totalRows = e.AffectedRows;

    count2.Text = "Showing " + startRowOnPage.ToString() +
                  " - " + lastRowOnPage + " of " + totalRows;
}
```

check this links

[Total Row Count SqlDataSource GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432757/total-row-count-sqldatasource-gridview)

[Records count in asp.net gridview with SQL data source & Paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20030679/records-count-in-asp-net-gridview-with-sql-data-source-paging)

or you can add `row_number` column as rowcount like

```
select row_number() over(order by pin) a , others column from yourtable
```